# Как убрать пустые скобки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске кода все работает, но не до конца исправно, ибо в местах где идут чётные числа остаются пустые скобки. Сам код сделан для фильтровки нечётных чисел и вывести те самые числа.
числа в txt файле:

```
12
45
76
3
2
77
95
48
245
866
81
37
50
```

```
with open("123.txt") as f:
    n = int(f.readline())
    for i in range  (n):
        a=map(int, f.readline().split())
        b = filter(lambda a: (a % 2 == 1), a)
        print(list(b))
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1315502/edit), пожалуйста, ваш вопрос, добавьте пример актуального и желаемого вывода программы.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код работает исправно и выводит ожидаемый результат - нечетные числа:

123.txt:

```
1
12 45 76 3 2 77 95 48 245 866 81 37 50
```

```py
with open("123.txt") as f:
n = int(f.readline())
for i in range(n):
    a=map(int, f.readline().split())
    b = filter(lambda a: (a % 2 == 1), a)
    print(list(b))
```

Вывод:

```py
[45, 3, 77, 95, 245, 81, 37]
```

Comment: я понять не могу как убрать пустые скобки, там где должны быть чётные числа но их код просто не выводит и пишет пустые скобки []

Comment: @ВоваСычук, верно, вы же отсеиваете все четные числа.

Comment: @ВоваСычук какие пустые скобки? Этот код не выводит никаких пустых скобок